# What will happen when I uninstall system apps? (I need to free up space)

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I need install a game update (1.9GB), but I have have 800 MB or so of internal storage left and I can't run the game on my sd card. I went through my apps and found that the largest one that I don't need was the "package installer" app, which is 800 MB. To my small knowledge, I need that app to install Apk's, but I can do it with other app installers. I haven't experimented with Android system files before, so I have no idea what will happen if uninstall Package Installer.

Edit: This now answered, thanks to advice. I'm just too stupid to find the check mark on my phone.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, you should mention what make/model of phone, OS version, as well if the device is rooted or not. You don't mention which "package installer"  but if its a system app, I would lean toward no if from a manufacturer or Google. Do check the wiki tag for [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory)

Comment: the apk is located /system therefore doesn't matter. when "uninstalling" the apk remains. However, it might free up some space used for update-apk, app data and dalvik-cache

Comment: Why don't you clear cache useless apps to free up space rather then uninstall system apps

Comment: Btw if its game update u can download apk and obb (including update) manually from google search and uninstall game, delete data make sure u backup progress online then install new Downloaded apk and place data in internal storage android/data/obb/*

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Comments are not really an answer though, so they can't be given a checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never touch to system apps but you can uninstall pre-installed apps like fb, google phots, MSO, ect, otherwise, why don't you buy a memory card and transfer unimportant apps to it.

Comment: I bought an SD card to run my games on it, but it didn't work. I transferred the game files to the sd card to see what happened and the game more less crashed. I have an Samsung Galaxy A20 and I can't find a way to move any app in it's entirety into my sd card

Comment: probably your phone does not support to move app from internal storage to sd card. there is another solution: simply use your sd card as internal storage, that's it, solved :-)

Comment: Supposing I do that with my 32GB card, (I dont know what card of cards you buy, I bought mine for some quick storage) I store all my games the card, what happens to my other apps? (100MB  apps for other uses)

Comment: when you use sd card as internal storage, your phone will keep the hard drive storage but will use sd card as it is an extension to phone storage, so all your previous apps and system apps remains safe and full functional.